# Embarcadero C++10.4.2 ignoring namespaces sometimes

Tags: c++builder

I am an experienced C++ developer, but new to Embarcadero.

I found the following code compiles, and it should not. What settings can I use to make the compiler be conformant?

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    auto ifs = ifstream("hellp");
}
```

Comment: Which platform are you compiling for, and with which C++ compiler (C++Builder has several). The only thing I see wrong with this code is the lack of `std::` in front of `ifstream`, which implies there is likely a `using namespace std;` or `using std::ifstream;` statement somewhere. The assignment of a temp object to a variable is fine, since `ifstream` supports move semantics in C++11 and later. Or the compiler may be using copy elision to optimize the copy away, as if you had written `ifstream ifs("hellp");` instead.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question: I am developing on Windows for 32-bit Windows, and on 10.4 update 2. I have since then discovered that defining _HAS_STRICT_CONFORMANCE would disable this and that _HAS_TRADITIONAL_IOSTREAMS is the direct cause for this misbehavior, but I have no idea how to set these macros.

Comment: And you were right of course - fstream has loads of using statements, injecting stuff from std into the global namespace. (This code is enabled only when _HAS_TRADITIONAL_IOSTREAMS is "true").

Comment: C++Builder 10.4 has **three** compilers for 32bit Windows (bcc32, bcc32c, and bcc32x). As for defining the macros, you can do that above the headers using `#define` statements, or you can define them in the Project Options, see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_Compiler_Directories_and_Conditionals

Comment: Thank you for the info. I happened to overlook that setting while searching and I failed to find any information regarding setting the compiler up. I apparently use bcc32c. Can you refer to any documentation in that direction, what the difference between the difference between the compilers is and how to choose an appropriate compiler?

Comment: [bcc32](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BCC32), [bcc32c](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BCC32C), [Win32 Clang-enhanced Compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Win32_Clang-enhanced_Compilers), [Clang-enhanced C++ Compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers)

Comment: Thank you. I notice that these compilers are based on clang 5.0 or older. That is quite a disappointment for me as it means I will have to rewrite quite a lot of code. Not your fault of course, and I appreciate your help.